# jquery fancybox 'maxHeigt' attr invalid

Tags: jquery, fancybox

The right behavior should be like this:
The height of the popup should grow dynamically as we add or remove rows. And it should have a scrollbar vertically when the height of popup > maxHeigh(we set)

The current behavior should be like this:

1. The popup would grow dynamically as we add or remove rows the first time, but when popup's height > maxHeight, there is no scrollbar appear.

[image]

2. After I close the popup and add rows again, scrollbar appear when popup's height > maxHeight.

[image]

Source code:

```
$.fancybox.open({
        href: '#advancedSearchWrapper',
        minHeight: 200,
        maxHeight: 450 ,
        fitToView: true,
        autoSize: false,
        autoWidth: true,
        modal: true,
        autoScale: true,
        padding: 30});
```

Comment: Upgrading to v3 would eliminate this issue, because you would be able to control width/height simply using CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Janis, now my the version of fancybox is 2.1.0. If not upgarding to v3. Do you have a better way to fix this issue?